# Overwrite specific XML node

Tags: c#, xml, .net-2.0, .net-4.5

I have a XML file of the following format:

```
<Alarms>
   <Alarm>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Severity>Warning</Severity>
      <Comments></Comments>
   </Alarm>
   <Alarm>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Severity>Error</Severity>
      <Comments>Restart the machine</Comments>
   </Alarm>
   ...
```

My program has a GUI which gives the user the ability to edit the `Comments` of an alarm. I am trying to come up with the best solution for the actions to take when a user is done editing and wants to save the changes. The XML file isn't extremely large (it does not warrant a database) but large enough that I do not want to overwrite the entire thing every time a change is made to a single alarm. Is it possible to target only a specific node and edit the `Comments` attribute without then having to re-write everything?

I'm looking for a XML-specific solution... I want to avoid regular flat-file methods that involve going to a specific line in a file and then editing that line. Perhaps something exists for XML files that I'm not privy to. I'm currently working with a .NET 2 project but will soon be upgrading to 4.5, so any solution works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load up the xml in XmlDocument class. Navigate with an XPath query to the Comments node you want to edit and change the value. When you are done, just save the document to the same file name or a different one.

Here is an example using a Console Application.

```
// The Id of the Alarm to edit
int idToEdit = 2;

// The new comment for the Alarm
string newCommentValue = "Here is a new comment";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

XmlNode commentsElement = doc.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("Alarms/Alarm[Id = '{0}']/Comments", idToEdit));
commentsElement.InnerText = newCommentValue;

doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eQROet

Comment: Do you know the inner workings of `XmlDocument.Save()`? There are several overloads using different writers (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.save(v=vs.110).aspx) and I'm trying to find one that is most efficient for my use case.

Comment: You will probably want the overload that takes a string, which will save the document contents to a file path. This does end up writing the whole file to disk again, which really is not a big deal. If you are concerned with writing the whole file to disk, consider saving each Alarm as a separate file with the alarm id in the file name. This way when you modify a file, you are just saving the changes to one alarm.